# Android changes the time zone set programmatically for UTC date string

Tags: java, java-time

**Update**: problem solved,there is no issue with the java code snipped I used, the problem was related to errors in the data set.

The API I work on return flights departure times set with UTC format

```
2023-07-24T15:19:00.000Z
```

And if the flight departs from Ireland, I set the time zone to Europe/Dublin because I want the departure time to reflects the actual departume time in Ireland

```
String output =
        Instant.parse(dateTime)
                .atZone(ZoneId.of( "Europe/Dublin" ))
                .format(
                        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")
                );
```

Here is my problem: the app does not display the time set for Dublin, it always display the time set with the time zone defined in the phone.

That's an issue because if a flight departs at `08:00` in Ireland and the user uses the app from France, I don't want `09:00` (+1 hour) to be displayed because it can be misleading. I want `08:00` to be displayed

How can I make this happen?
Many thanks

Comment: *Here is my problem: the app does not display the time set for Dublin, it always displays the time set with the time zone defined in the phone.* - how is it possible? Are you saying that the app changes the code to `.atZone(ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" ))` when someone uses it from France? This will be disastrous if apps start working like that - won't it be? Your code looks correct to me and you should not worry unless there is something else which you have not mentioned in your question.

Comment: Edit the example values in your prose to match the example data in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No such problem

Your code is correct and functioning properly.

The offset used by that time zone is one hour ahead of UTC. [Dublin time](https://time.is/Dublin) in the summer of 2023 is +01:00.

So your code has an input of 3 PM (15 hour) in UTC, and an output of 4 PM (16 hour) in Dublin time. That result is correct.

```
    String output =
     Instant.parse( "2023-07-24T15:19:00.000Z" )  // Returns an `Instant` object. 
            .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Dublin" ) )  // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object. 
            .format(
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")  // Returns a `DateTimeFormatter` object. 
            );
    System.out.println( output ) ;
```

See this code [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/WKgc6L).

> 16:19

## Default zone irrelevant

The current default time zone of the JVM does *not* affect this result.

You can see this fact on the linked Ideone.com page where the default zone is UTC (GMT), an offset of +00:00. Your `ZonedDateTime` carries the correct expected time zone of `Europe/Dublin` regardless of the JVM’s default.

Comment: You are right, there was an error in the json response with wrong values in the data set, hence false positive regarding the issue I encounter. Many thanks for your piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

To display the UTC time in the app without adjusting for the phone's local time zone, you can use the **OffsetDateTime** class to parse the UTC date string instead of **Instant**. By using **OffsetDateTime**, you can explicitly represent the date and time with the UTC offset, which ensures that the time zone of the phone won't affect the displayed time.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class TimeConversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTime = "2023-07-24T15:19:00.000Z";

        OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTime);
        String output = offsetDateTime.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Dublin"))
                .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));

        System.out.println(output); // Output: 16:19
    }
}
```

Comment: You’ve misunderstood the issue. The code in the Question is not using `Instant`. The method in the second call, `Instant#atZone`, returns a `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: Also, `OffsetDateTime` is the wrong class to use here. Time zone work should be done with `ZonedDateTime` as seen in Question.